# Convert Unique Integer To Unique String In PHP

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to convert a unique number of say 12 digits, into a unique alphabetic code of the same length?

So if I'm using the date to produce a unique ID number:

```
id = date("Hsdmiy"); = 125522104519
```

I'd like to reproduce that as `hruurrhxiuhn`, for example.

Possibly using:

```
new_id = ( [?],$id );
```

Where `?` = some conversion formula.

The `new_id` must be as unique as the numeric `id`

Any ideas how to create this in `PHP`?

Comment: 1. `date("Hsdmiy")` is not unique at all. 2. you can use `chr` function to convert each digit int to single character string

Comment: How is it not unique? As time is constantly moving the number is always going to be different

Comment: What if you run the script twice a second?

Comment: It's hardly likely that I'm going to be uploading 2 articles to my blog in the same second - or minute for that matter.

Comment: I still think it's not a good idea (you can use `uniqid` function and then convert it to dec) or use some autoincerement value in db (I don't know your use-case)

Comment: Back to the point @PavelTřupek, how does `chr` function work for my example? I run it through `https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_chr` and all it returns is a strange symbol

Comment: for each digit call `chr(97+$digit)` and you'll get `a-j` chars

Comment: Using `uniqid` isn't a bad idea, even though it's longer than my 12 digit current id. Is this number always 13 characters? Also, w3cschools says `The generated ID from this function does not guarantee uniqueness of the return value` - What's the deal with that?

Comment: uniqid also uses time to get unique string, but you can set second parameter  $more_entropy = true to increase chance of uniqueness

Comment: I've also added one solution as answer...

Comment: Alternatively I could create a `rand(100,999)` to create a 3 digit number added to the end of the `uniqid`. With a `-` this would make it 15 characters. But is `uniqid` always 13?

Comment: Uniqid is not random, but really close to it. I dont know what for do you want to use it. And about the length - as manual says "With an empty prefix, the returned string will be 13 characters long. If more_entropy is TRUE, it will be 23 characters."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple string replacement:

```
$new_id = str_replace(range(0, 9), range('z', 'q'), $id);
```

You can replace `range('z', 'q')` with anything.  Another range or array `['x', 'h', 'r' . . .]` or whatever.

Comment: If you read that last comment, please ignore it. This works great.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I don't recommend it, but you can use this code:

```
echo implode('', array_map(function($x) { return chr(97+$x); }, str_split('125522104519')));
```

And explanation:

```
echo 
  implode( //implode array of strings to the one string
    '', 
    array_map( //for each char in your array of digits call function:
       function($x) { return chr(97+$x); }, // return char a-j
       str_split('125522104519') //split string to array
    )
  );
```